# Error 1053 while starting user-defined service

Tags: windows-services, tomcat6

I have created a service using sc.exe for tomcat6.exe. The command is:

```
sc.exe create "Tomcat Service" binPath= "D:\tomcat\bin\tomcat.exe
```

Creating the service was successful, but I get the following error while starting the service.

```
Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
```

Both starting from cmd using `sc.exe start "Tomcat Server"` and services.msc result in the same error.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Tomcat.exe is a true windows service, installing it with SC is not good enough. Install Tomcat 6 as a service [using the "service.bat" file or by composing your own command line options for tomcat6.exe](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services) (including the //IS// parameter).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but not exactly tomcat as a service, but any service I create using sc.exe gives me the same error. I tried the same for VLC Player also. I got the same error-@CoreTech

Comment: Yes, that is because SC doesn't work on executables not explicitly written to be a Windows Service. If you give it a regular application, the service will fail with error 1053. You'll need a "service wrapper" [(like Microsoft's Srvany)](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) to adapt a regular application to run as a service.